# Computer freezing with when connecting Dell Dock

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, dell

I am a n00b when it comes to the Linux Desktop. I have a Precision 7530 laptop. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. The first time I connected the Dell dock (Wd19DC) I was able to set up the displays how I wanted it. After I disconnected the dock it took 1-2 minutes (with Windows 7 it was almost instant). I then re-connected to the dock and nothing. I went to the monitor settings to investigate further and then then laptop froze. There seems to be some issue here with the dock and or drivers. Where should I start looking? (e.g. Should I post here the output of /var/log/syslog) ? Are there any specific drivers that I need to get it working "correctly"?

Comment: Is the dock connected via Thunderbolt? If so you might need to change the security features for thunderbolt in the Bios. Also check if the dock and the computer are running the newest firmware (use Dells Support Website).

Comment: I took a look at this(https://www.dellemc.com/resources/en-us/asset/data-sheets/products/electronics-accessories/dell_performance_dock_wd19dc_spec_sheet.pdf), and it seems the Dell Dock supports Ubuntu 18.04. Since it is connected via thunderbolt, does the thunderbolt tab on settings show anything?